# Creating and Accessing Databases WITHOUT MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

I'm having troubles installing MySQL, is there any way to use databases without MySQL?

For exmaple, are there any database files that I can put in my website root directory?

Comment: There are *plenty* of databases.  You can use Oracle, DB2 or PostgresSQL.  You can use CouchDB, MongoDB or BaseX.  You can read and write a flat file; you can use Sqlite.

Comment: But to effectively use *any* database, you need a clue.  MySQL *should* be pretty easy to use and install.  Perhaps your best bet is to troubleshoot what's going wrong with MySQL.  Before you jump off on a different track (and, in all likelihood, a fresh set of problems).  IMHO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite (PHP API)](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) is a file-based database, but it must be installed as well. However, since it doesn't run a server it is easier to manage than a server-based RDBMS like MySQL. It is recommended only for low traffic, low volume sites.

You *should not* store the database at the site root, however.  The file should be stored outside the site's document root so it is not accessible from the web.

[(SQLite homepage)](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You might give sqlite a try: http://www.sqlite.org/about.html.

Have you submitted questions about your installation difficulty on here or on superuser?

Comment: I have, but the log files are empty.